# Left join on column isn't in the relationship between two tables

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, left-join

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE plans
    (id int, benefit varchar(5), clip_state int);

INSERT INTO plans
    (id, benefit, clip_state)
VALUES
    (1, 'A', 1),
    (2, 'A', 0),
    (3, 'B', 0),
    (4, 'C', 0);

CREATE TABLE clip_states
    (state varchar(2), clip_state int);

INSERT INTO clip_states
    (state, clip_state)
VALUES
    ('LA', 1),
    ('FL', 0);
```

Please noted that the `clip_state` is either 0 or 1 and the data model allows to query for **one or no** plan in `plans` table from 2 information: `benefit` & `state`. First, using `benefit` condition, we can filter the `plans` table to 2 rows at most, one with `clip_state` = 0, and one = 1. Then by using `state` and join with the `clip_states` table, we can reduce the result to one row (or zero) by checking:

- If the `state` is in `clip_states` table, make sure the `clip_state` is matched between 2 tables. If no match, no result returned.
- If the `state` doesn't exist in `clip_states`, it only matches with the row in `plans` table that has `clip_state` = 0.

Here is my query that does the trick:

```
SELECT id, p.clip_state, benefit
FROM plans p
LEFT JOIN clip_states cs ON STATE IN ('LA')
WHERE benefit = 'A' AND
(p.clip_state = cs.clip_state OR (p.clip_state = 0 AND cs.clip_state IS NULL));
```

As you can see, the *left join* is quite strange because it doesn't join on the relationship between the 2 tables. So, my question is:

- Is it normal to have such kind of join?
- Is there any better solution (clean & performance)?

You can check my solution at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/8912d/53

Updated 1: I have updated the text of the question above.

Updated 2: More information

1. If a `state` isn't in `clip_states` table, its `clip_state` implicitly equals to 0. Otherwise, its `clip_state` is in the table.
2. From the two given info: `benefit` and `state`, find a row in `plans` table where `plans.clip_state` = `clip_state` of that given `state`. Of course if it doesn't match, no row returned.

Comment: Are you sure your query "does the trick"? It didn't return any rows for me when `benefit = B` on your sqlfiddle.

Comment: Does your using `STATE IN ('LA')` instead of `STATE = 'LA'` imply that the query should also be runnable for multiple states specified? If so, what would results for multiple states look like? Should it be 1 or 0 rows per state? Or just 1 or 0 rows for the bunch of states?

Comment: @bmewsing: Yup it does. Because if (benefit, state) = ('B', 'LA'). There is no match.

Comment: @AndriyM: Yup, I should change this because it doesn't fit in this situation. However, the real problem isn't completely covered in my question. It needs to find a plan for a bunch of states that have the same clip_state.

Comment: Can there be multiple rows per state in `clip_states`. Please clarify your data model, showing primary keys and other relevant constraints. Also clarify the problem: are you checking for a single state or multiple states like you mention in the comment? And what are the requirements for multiple states? This is most probably a simple problem, your definition is what complicates it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: state is the primary key of clip_states. Don't worry about multiple states. Just one benefit & one state, find one or no matched row.

Comment: Can there be a row `(5, 'D', 1)` in `plans` - being the only row for `'D'`? And should it be returned if no matching row is found in `clip_states`? What is the primary key for table `plans`? Any other constraints on it? Please edit your question to clean up.

Comment: I don't understand this: how can it be that “if it doesn't match, no row returned” and “implicitly equals to 0” are active at the same time? It is either no rows *or* a row based on the implicit default.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English as it caused the trouble of understanding. But why don't you guys just combine all the specified rules using "AND"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I have to use the following query as the solution. I have checked the query plan and see it one step better than my query in the question. The idea is to narrow down plan first, then join with the clip_states table.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT id, clip_state, benefit
    FROM plans
    WHERE benefit = 'A') p
LEFT JOIN clip_states cs ON state IN ('LA')
WHERE (p.clip_state = cs.clip_state OR (p.clip_state = 0 AND cs.clip_state IS NULL));
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

#### Updated Answer to updated question:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM   plans p
WHERE  p.benefit = 'A'
AND    NOT  EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   clip_states cs
  WHERE  cs.state = 'LA'
  AND    cs.clip_state <> p.clip_state
  )
ORDER  BY p.clip_state
LIMIT  1;
```

[->sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/8912d/205)

That could be the definition:

1. Find all rows in table `plans` for a given `benefit`.
2. Eliminate rows where `clip_state` does not match
   the same column in table `clip_states` for a given `state`.
3. From the remaining rows, return the one with the lowest value in `clip_state`.

Also, since

> `clip_state` is either 0 or 1

you should be using data type [`boolean`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-boolean.html) instead of `int`.

Comment: This is more or less what I came up with for a single state. I used `ORDER BY cs.state IS NULL DESC` and I kept the OP's `IN`, although this solution clearly makes most sense with a single state only, so I completely agree with your switching to `=`.

Comment: Yup, it is correct for all the testcases I gave. Unfortunately, it failed if (benefit, state) is ("B", "LA"). See, it isn't as easy as its look. That's why I had to do a weird join.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how that fails. Seems to me it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/8912d/185

Comment: Because the row returned from plans table has clip_state = 0 whereas the clip_state for 'LA' is 1. It should return no row in this case. Please read my latest updates.

Comment: Sorry, it isn't correct. See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/b0feb/26 It should return no row. BTW, once you have a solution, please compare to my solution as I need to pick the better one.

Comment: @instcode: I *did* address that case repeatedly - in my first version (see edit history) and again in the comments above. You didn't respond. Should have been in your test case to begin with. In this case I think the query in your question is already the optimum. Just make sure you have proper *indexes*.

Answer (score 1):

A completely different approach:

1. "Add" the required state to the `clip_states` table with the `clip_state` of 0, if that state isn't already in the table.
2. Inner join the resulting set to `plans` on `clip_state`, additionally filtering on `state`.

This is what it might look like:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM plans p
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT state, clip_state FROM clip_states
  UNION ALL
  (
  SELECT 'LA', 0
  EXCEPT
  SELECT state, 0 FROM clip_states
  )
) cs
ON p.clip_state = cs.clip_state
WHERE p.benefit = 'A'
  AND cs.state = 'LA'
;
```

Here's this query "in action": http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/b0feb/7

Seems consistent with your requirements, unless I've missed something again.

Comment: This works with all testcases I can think of. How is it comparing to my solution? (I'm not a db guy)

Comment: Can't help you there, I'm afraid. I'm a developer, not a DBA. Not particularly good at query tuning/analysing at the moment. Besides, this is PostgreSQL, which I've never worked with. (If it were not for SQL Fiddle, I would actually have had nowhere to test this.) Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `LEFT JOIN` looks strange here.

1. I see no joining conditions between `plans` and `clip_states` tables;
2. You don't use any columns from `clip_state` in your SELECT-list, so you cannot get `NULL` values which you aim for.

I recommend doing it the following way (also on [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/8912d/7)):

```
SELECT id, p.benefit, coalesce(cs.clip_state, 0) clip_state
FROM plans p
LEFT JOIN clip_states cs ON cs.clip_state=p.clip_state AND cs.state IN ('LA')
WHERE p.benefit = 'A';
```

1. I've moved a join condition from `WHERE` to the `FROM` part of the query and simplified it;
2. I've added column from the `clip_states` table in to the SELECT-list, it can be `NULL` in case there're no matching rows;
3. When `cs.clip_state` is `NULL`, I turn it into 0, as expected.

I think this does what you need.

Please, take a look at this [Visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html), I find it very usefull.

Comment: My reading is, `plans.clip_state` **must** be 0 if there's no match with the `clip_states` subset.

Comment: @AndriyM, perhaps you're right. I was confused by *(means, by default `clip_state` for a `state` is 0)* statement.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that it does the trick:

- Is it normal to have such kind of join?

It is not how it's usually done. But the way I see it, JOIN just takes a condition after ON which could be any condition.

- Is there any better solution (clean & performance)?

It looks like the shortest solution available here and I don't see why it should impair performance.

If you create a VIEW from this query and include the STATE field in the selected fields, you can make a query from this view like this:

```
SELECT * FROM stateview WHERE state='FL'
```

*By the way, coincidentally I guess, the solution provided by vyegorov is exactly what I entered in sql-fiddle to do some testing. But figured it wasn't correct so removed it sometime after that.*